# Get XML from different Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

Good day to you!

I have a question. Can't get how combine 2 tables in 1 result XML.

Here is the sample

```
DECLARE @t1 table (ID int identity(1,1), SomeField varchar(50))
DECLARE @t2 table (ID int identity(1,1), SomeField varchar(50), AnotherField varchar(50))

INSERT INTO @t1 (SomeField) VALUES ('rec1'),('rec2'),('rec3'),('rec4')
INSERT INTO @t2 (SomeField,AnotherField) VALUES ('s106','here'),('s12','just'),('s13','sample')

SELECT * FROM @t1 AS FirstTable
SELECT * FROM @t2 AS AnotherTable
```

Wanted result:

```
<Root>
    <FirstTable ID="1" SomeField="rec1" />
    <FirstTable ID="2" SomeField="rec2" />
    <FirstTable ID="3" SomeField="rec3" />
    <FirstTable ID="4" SomeField="rec4" />
    <AnotherTable ID="1" SomeField="s106" AnotherField="here" />
    <AnotherTable ID="2" SomeField="s12" AnotherField="just" />
    <AnotherTable ID="3" SomeField="s13" AnotherField="sample" />
</Root>
```

dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=7902cfa77d8594cd127a53a8c692608b)

## New remark (edited)

answered by [John Cappelletti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1570000/john-cappelletti), but need put all this inside third table.

Here is new code:

```
DECLARE @t1 table (ID int identity(1,1), tID int, SomeField varchar(50))
DECLARE @t2 table (ID int identity(1,1), tID int, SomeField varchar(50), AnotherField varchar(50))
DECLARE @t3 table (ID int identity(1,1), field1 varchar(50), field2 varchar(50))


INSERT INTO @t1 (tID,SomeField) VALUES (1,'rec1'),(1,'rec2'),(1,'rec3'),(1,'rec4')
INSERT INTO @t2 (tID,SomeField,AnotherField) VALUES (1,'s106','here'),(1,'s12','just'),(1,'s13','sample')
INSERT INTO @t3 (field1,field2) VALUES ('field1 Value','field2 Value')
```

Wanted result (finally):

```
<ThirdTable ID="1" field1="field1 Value" field2="field2 Value">
    <FirstTable ID="1" tID="1" SomeField="rec1" />
    <FirstTable ID="2" tID="1" SomeField="rec2" />
    <FirstTable ID="3" tID="1" SomeField="rec3" />
    <FirstTable ID="4" tID="1" SomeField="rec4" />
    <AnotherTable ID="1" tID="1" SomeField="s106" AnotherField="here" />
    <AnotherTable ID="2" tID="1" SomeField="s12" AnotherField="just" />
    <AnotherTable ID="3" tID="1" SomeField="s13" AnotherField="sample" />
</ThirdTable>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Added for the Extended Question**

```
Select *
      ,(select cast(
                     isnull((Select * From @t1 for xml raw('FirstTable')),'')
                    +isnull((Select * From @t2 for xml raw('AnotherTable')),'')
               as xml)
       ) 
 From @t3 for xml raw('ThirdTable')
```

Returns

```
<ThirdTable ID="1" field1="field1 Value" field2="field2 Value">
  <FirstTable ID="1" tID="1" SomeField="rec1" />
  <FirstTable ID="2" tID="1" SomeField="rec2" />
  <FirstTable ID="3" tID="1" SomeField="rec3" />
  <FirstTable ID="4" tID="1" SomeField="rec4" />
  <AnotherTable ID="1" tID="1" SomeField="s106" AnotherField="here" />
  <AnotherTable ID="2" tID="1" SomeField="s12" AnotherField="just" />
  <AnotherTable ID="3" tID="1" SomeField="s13" AnotherField="sample" />
</ThirdTable>
```

Comment: Wow, that's amazing! Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, I found that structure is the most optimal then get every table separated or DataSet. But I found interesting thing if table 't1' don't have records, table 't2' will not added too...

Comment: @ArkadiyV. East trap.  You can use concat() if 2012+ or wrap the inner selects with an IsNull().

Comment: Oh yeah! Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

```
Select [root] = cast((Select * From @t1 for xml raw('FirstTable'))
                    +(Select * From @t2 for xml raw('AnotherTable'))
                as xml)
For XML Path(''),Type
```

Returns

```
<root>
  <FirstTable ID="1" SomeField="rec1" />
  <FirstTable ID="2" SomeField="rec2" />
  <FirstTable ID="3" SomeField="rec3" />
  <FirstTable ID="4" SomeField="rec4" />
  <AnotherTable ID="1" SomeField="s106" AnotherField="here" />
  <AnotherTable ID="2" SomeField="s12" AnotherField="just" />
  <AnotherTable ID="3" SomeField="s13" AnotherField="sample" />
</root>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok, i cant post new question so I'll do it here